# How to find out which derived class is processing

Tags: c++

I have a BaseInterface class, with a virtual void execute() to be implemented by derived classes:

```
class BaseInterface
{
public:
    virtual void execute(int a) = 0;
}
```

And I have tons of derived classes overwriting the execute void:

```
class ProcessN : public BaseInterface
{
public:
    void execute(int a);
}
```

Execute void of one of my derived classes has a bug. But there are tons of derived classes. It is very difficult to check each of them one by one. I have difficulties in finding the bug.

Is there a method in C++ to find out via base class, which derived class is currently processing over it?

EDIT:
Ok I improve my question after a useful discussion on the comments:

May I implement something inside the constructor of the BaseInterface class, to print out the info of the current processing derived class?

Comment: If you have been able to identify that one of the deriving classes has a bug in `execute`, presumably there is some code like so `ptrToBaseIntfThatPointsToObjOfProcessK->execute(0);` somewhere that triggers the bug?  Consider setting up a conditional breakpoint in your debugger.

Comment: The bug is not simply debuggable, it makes a visual difference on the view.

Comment: Is it possible to get a ptrofderivedclass from the constructor of the base class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How is execute being invoked....May be you can introduce a static method in base class which takes a Baseclass pointer as argument and call this method before execute and print the necessary information from the derived object in this method using BasePointer to see which derived class object it is.
Per my understanding I suggested as below. If it does not help All the best.

```
class Base
{
   public:
   virtual void exec(int i) =0 ;
   static void check(Base* temp)
   {
     cout<<"Type of obj"<<typeid(*temp).name()<<endl;
    }
 };
class Derived1 : public Base
{
 public:
 void exec(int i)
 {
  cout<<"Der1 Exe "<<i<<endl;
  }
 };

class Derived2 : public Base
{    
 public: 
 void exec(int i)
 {
   cout<<"Der2 Exe "<<i<<endl;

 }
};
int main()
{   
  Base *client = NULL;  
  Derived1 lder1;
  Derived2 lder2;
  client= &lder2;
  Base::check(client);
  client->exec(0);

  client= &lder1;
  Base::check(client);
  client->exec(0);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey Munni, I ask if there is a way without touching the derived objects.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for typeid

```
BaseInterface *a = new Process1();
BaseInterface *b = new Process2();

cout << typeid(*a).name() << endl;
cout << typeid(*b).name() << endl;
```

Or if you want to use inside your execute() you can just simply use typeid(*this)

```
class BaseInterface
{
public:
    virtual void execute(int a) = 0;
    //debug helper
    void print_info() { cout << typeid(*this).name() << endl; }
};

class ProcessN : public BaseInterface
{
    void execute(int a) { print_info(); }
};
```

Comment: Again here, we check all processes one by one, dont we?

Comment: You are not describing your problem clear enough. What do you want to do? Your process1 to N will run one by one and whenever there's a bug, you write to log file or print it to stdio in each execute so you know which one is running currently?

Comment: I can do the same thing with writing cout << "Hello I am ProcessX" << endl; inside each deriving class. I need a method to write once inside derived class and get the output whenever a deriving class works on it.

Comment: For the cout << "processX" solution, you need to put different stuff in each processX. Now you only need the print_info() which is all same in different processX. Now seems you want to differentiate which ProcessX class is running execute (do you?), and you don't want to modify execute functions in ProcessX at all, I am afraid there's no way to do this. Because when a ProcessX is running execute, there's no way that its Base knows ProcessX is running unless you modify execute function and let the Base know it.

Comment: May I not implement something inside the constructor of the BaseInterface, to write out the info of the current deriving class?

Comment: You can register each instanced ProcessX in Base constructor, but you still won't know which ProcessX is executing without modifying execute() function in ProcessX.

Comment: In how many places and how do you call execute? Maybe something can be done there.

Comment: There are 40-50 different process classes, each being invoked from different parts of the program, and each having its own implementation of execute() void.

Comment: I found the current bug when checking again all processes one by one. Anyway my question is still valid as a general question.

Comment: I thought for sure by now somebody would correct your use of 'Derived' to mean 'Base'. Very confusing when reading your question and responses. I'm also wondering why you need so many derived classes, but then that's not the question here.

Comment: @codah You are right, when I tried to answer the question, I tried not to use his term. In Rancs' post, deriving class is actually the derived class in our normal sense, and derived class is actually the base class in our normal sense.

Comment: Hey sorry for unregular usage of the terms, the English is not my native language. I will check them. For the question of why we need so many derived classes: think for example plugins of a image manipulating program. Each plugin makes its own different process on the image.